# Customize header and footer in WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress

I am currently working on a WordPress site with hardcoded values in the header and footer. I'd like to make both the header and footer editable from within the WP Admin, but am not sure the best route. Any thoughts on best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Admin/Appearance/Widgets.
I recommend you create a widget that allows the footer to be edited.
This scenario is vastly used when web-developers are handing over the freedom for editing to their clients. This minimizes the risk of faults while editing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you think this is better than creating a "Header" and "Footer" page and using advanced custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you have menus in header and footer then, you can create a menu in apperance->menus in wp-admin and call it in footer by their ID (theme-location).

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Any other text can be printed in header and footer by created widgets as answered above..